# How do make a telegram bot to read a pdf file sent by user and extract data from it?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, chatbot, python-telegram-bot

I have been checking on forums(stack overflow, git, Telegram APIs) to check how could I extract contents from a pdf file which is sent by user? I have created Telegram bot using python's `python-telegram-bot` library and as an efforts to try to solve my question, I had checked links eg: https://pypi.org/project/python-telegram-bot/ and https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html in search of functions but couldn't find anything there.

I did find methods to send a pdf file to user from bot and send a file from user to bot but there is nothing available where BOT can extract contents of pdf sent by user. Will be grateful if experts could guide me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python-telegram-bot` is a library that provides a wrapper for the [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api). As such, it provides all the methods from the API as well as auxiliary functionality to build chat bots *in general*, including [downloading files sent by users](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#downloading-a-file). Extracting contents from a received PDF file after download is however far beyond the scope of this library.

Of course there are other libraries that provide such functionality and that can be used in combinantion with `python-telgram-bot`. See e.g. [`camelot`](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Thanks a TON for your answer. So you mean I can save file send by user into server's location/filesystem and then can extract details from it? Am I right here, kindly confirm once.

Comment: Yes, that's what you can do. To be precise, you usually don't even need to write the downloaded data into a file - in most cases it suffices to keep the data in memory.

Comment: Sure, I will try it out and let you know then. I have accepted this answer now, in case of any further information needs to be added I will inform here, thank you.